# service worker skipWaiting and clients.claim not taking control of browser on first load

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, service-worker

Right now my service worker looks like this:

```
self.addEventListener('install', event => {
  console.log('V1 installing…')
  self.skipWaiting()

  event.waitUntil(
    caches
      .open('sw-cache')
      .then(cache =>
        cache.addAll([
          '/assets/img/bbcourt-2pt.png',
          '/assets/img/bbcourt-3pt.png'
        ])
      )
  )
})

self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
  self.clients.claim()
  console.log('V1 now ready to handle fetches!')
})

self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  const url = new URL(event.request.url)

  if (
    url.origin == location.origin &&
    url.pathname == '/assets/img/bbcourt-2pt.png'
  ) {
    event.respondWith(caches.match('/assets/img/bbcourt-2pt.png'))
  }

  if (
    url.origin == location.origin &&
    url.pathname == '/assets/img/bbcourt-3pt.png'
  ) {
    event.respondWith(caches.match('/assets/img/bbcourt-3pt.png'))
  }
})
```

Currently, I'm trying to use self.skipWaiting() and self.clients.claim() to take control of the browser with this service worker immediately so that even when I go to the page with bbcourt-2pt.png and bbcourt-3pt.png while offline on the first load the cached images are still served up by the service worker. However, the service worker doesn't seem to be taking over on first load still. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi Stephen, did you have any update on this ? I'm experiencing the same trouble randomly which fades when restarting the browser...